# Using UI objects outside OnCreate Method

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Im a total newbie in creating android applications. I can use the objects from the AXML inside the OnCreate method, but i can't use them inside the event handler radioButton_Click.I wan't to know how to use them in the event handler radioButton_Click.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        RadioButton radioButton1 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButton1);
        RadioButton radioButton2 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButton2);
        radioButton1.Click += radioButton_Click;
        radioButton2.Click += radioButton_Click;
        //radioButton1 and radioButton2 are recognized here.
    }

    void radioButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //radioButton1 and radioButton2 are not recognized here.
        //I want to know how to use IN THIS METHOD the objects loaded from the AXML
        // in OnCreate (the two radio buttons)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may have to create this variables as class member variables.

```
RadioButton radioButton1;
RadioButton radiobutton2;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    radioButton1 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButton1);
    radioButton2 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButton2);
    radioButton1.Click += radioButton_Click;
    radioButton2.Click += radioButton_Click;
    //radioButton1 and radioButton2 are recognized here.
}

void radioButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //radioButton1 and radioButton2 are not recognized here.
    //I want to know how to use IN THIS METHOD the objects loaded from the AXML
    // in OnCreate (the two radio buttons)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside you Activity, create fields (better to be private) of RadioButtons.
this will help you to use them at the global scope.

notice to cast the finding by FindViewById!